# Running ssl on apache, Xampp

Tags: apache, ssl

I have **xampp** installed on my vps. My website works perfect now. But I need to run my website with **ssl**.

I've read many tutorials about it and most of them was the same. Anyway, I did what they told. And anything doesn't work for me.

I've created certificates with ssh not with a CA authority. It's just for test.

I've edited **php.ini** file to enable ssl extension.

I've edited **httpd-ssl.conf** and **httpd-vhosts.conf** files.

Here is my **httpd-vhosts.conf** file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin info@example.com
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com:8080
ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443> 
DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\ 
ServerName example.com
<Directory C:\xampp\htdocs\n> 
AllowOverride All 
Allow from All 
</Directory> 
SSLEngine on 
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL 
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt" 
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key" 
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|pl|asp|php)$"> 
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars 
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0 
</VirtualHost>
```

When I type https://example.com or example.com:443 website doesn't open.

Any solution?

---

**Update:**

Here is the log in apache error logs file:

> [Fri Sep 23 19:09:11.355966 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2616:tid 284]
>   AH01909: example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID
>   which matches the server name

Comment: " doesn't work for me." is a about the most useless thing anyone can say to describe an error. Can you clarify the "doesn't work"? What happens? What did you expect it to happen?. Also about the warning, it's just a warning that does not prevent httpd from functioning. Things you must try: 1º accesing locally and with ip to discard a dns issue, 2º make a certificate which CN matches the name in the "ServerName" directive to get rid of that warning.

Comment: I've told what is not working at the end of question. And I said what I want. The server name in certificate and config file are the same. I have no idea what is this error for.

Comment: Clearly the CN in the certificate does not match the ServerName you defined it if HTTPD complains about it. Anyways, glad you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Firewall was blocking port 443. Now it's open and there is no problem.